# Automatically sync copied google spreadsheet with original spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

After making a copy of a google spreadsheet, I would like to have the copied spreadsheet automatically sync any changes made to the original spreadsheet. Is this already being done? If not, how do I make it so?

The syncing is only one-way -> from original to copied.

It will be a hassle make copies of the original spreadsheet whenever new changes are made.

Comment: You can do it with [Importrange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

Comment: Does "any changes" means only value changes or you are interested too in changes to sheet names, cell formatting, data validation, etc? Please also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

1. To start, open up the spreadsheet or tab you want to copy to the new Sheet > copy the sheet’s URL
2. Make a note of the cells you want to import
3. Open the new sheet where you want the data to appear
   In the cell begin to type > =IMPORTRANGE (you’ll see the code as you begin to type)
4. Type > quotation “ (very important) then paste the URL from the sheet and add another quotation mark at the end of the URL
5. Then add a comma , > quotation mark again “ > then type the exact name of the specific tab you want to copy followed by an exclamation mark!
6. Finally, type the range of cells you want to import eg: A1:A19 followed by “ quotation marks
7. Press > Enter and your data will now appear in your new Sheet

.

Examle:

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")

IMPORTRANGE(A2,"B2")
```

.
For more information look [HERE](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/sheets/sync-data-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another/) or [HERE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)